# What is the R equivalent if the scipy.optimize.dual_annealing function in Python

Tags: python, r, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, simulated-annealing

I am translating some code from Python to R, and am finding it hard to find the corresponding functions in each. In this particular case, the code I'm having trouble with is:

```
output = dual_annealing(
                    residuals_totalcases, x0=parameter_list, bounds=bounds_params
                )
```

From the `scipy.optimize.dual_annealing` documentation, I see that the function implements the Dual Annealing optimization.

What packages / functions in R would be equivalent to this?

From the R documentation I see that there's options with the `anneal` function in the [subselect](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/subselect/versions/0.14/topics/anneal) package , as well as `GenSA` function in the [GenSA](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GenSA/GenSA.pdf) package, as well as some others.

These all seem to use simulated annealing, but no one discusses dual annealing, which python docs describe as " This stochastic approach derived from the generalization of CSA (Classical Simulated Annealing) and FSA (Fast Simulated Annealing) coupled to a strategy for applying a local search on accepted locations. "

Can anyone offer any clarification? TIA

Answer (score 1):

It is this package: GenSA: Generalized Simulated Annealing, located at

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GenSA/index.html,
with the accompanying paper:

Y. Xiang, S. Gubian. B. Suomela, J. Hoeng (2013). Generalized Simulated Annealing for Efficient Global Optimization: the GenSA Package for R. The R Journal, Volume 5/1, June 2013

The scipy documentation references this model as reference #5, saying that they are alternative implementations of each other.